# write bash function to drop user using sqlplus

Tags: linux, bash, sqlplus

I have written a small bash script to delete some rows from a table and drop some users using sqlplus. When I put the code in the function it is giving "syntax error: unexpected end of file" error message. Below is the code. Please let me know how to fix it.

```
function reset_db
{
sqlplus user1/password1@${input} << eof
set timing off
set serveroutput on size 10000
set feedback off
spool logfile_$input.out

delete from table1 where component = 'XYZ';
delete from table2 where component = 'XYZ';
commit;
exit
eof

sqlplus dba_usr/dba_password@${input} << eof
set timing off
set serveroutput on size 10000
set feedback off
spool logfile_$input.out

drop user ABC cascade;
drop user DEF cascade;
drop user HIG cascade;
commit;
exit;
}
```

Comment: Seems like `$input` should be a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `eof` at the end of your second `sqlplus` command. Change this:

```
exit;
}
```

to this:

```
exit;
eof
}
```

Incidentally, you don't actually need to call `sqlplus` two separate times; you can use its `connect` command to drop one connection and open a new one:

```
function reset_db
{

sqlplus user1/password1@${input} << eof

set timing off
set serveroutput on size 10000
set feedback off
spool logfile_$input.out

delete from table1 where component = 'XYZ';
delete from table2 where component = 'XYZ';
commit;

connect dba_usr/dba_password@${input}

drop user ABC cascade;
drop user DEF cascade;
drop user HIG cascade;

eof

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works! But I am able to see the SQL feedback on the screen which I don't want. How can I fix this one?

Also I want to update my script. I want to store all the db users in a list and then drop all of them. I think I need to use pl/sql for this, good place to learn it may be :)

Comment: How to turn off the SQL feedback on the screen?

Comment: @Jodi: I'm not sure quite what you mean, but have you tried passing the `-S` or `-SILENT` option? Like, instead of writing `sqlplus user1/password1@${input}`, writing `sqlplus -S user1/password1@${input}`?